# CXF GZIP REST JAVA

Tags: java, rest, gzip, cxf

Can someone please give me quick tutorial about how to achieve GZIP using apache cxf in java for restful webservices. i have gone through the documentation of cxf and have used their steps but that doesnt give anything.

Thanks

Comment: What happens? What errors do you get?

Comment: What's your application container? It's far better to add this at the container level than the app level.

Comment: I dont get any errors, thats why i m asking how to do it ?? GZIP in CXF what all steps are required to achieve it .. ?

Comment: i am using tomcat for runnning the server.

Comment: Probably one of the best defined question title ever. Why do we even need tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had found this answer long back. Just posting it for future users if any. Below given configuration was required for GZIP:

```
<cxf:bus id="cxfBus">
  <cxf:features>
    <bean class="org.apache.cxf.transport.common.gzip.GZIPFeature">
      <property name="threshold">
        <value>5</value>
      </property>
    </bean>
  </cxf:features>
</cxf:bus>
```